# Checking Linearity of operator

Tags: operator-theory

Operators A and B are defined as $$Af(x)=f(x)+x$$ and $$Bf(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}+2f(x)$$ check for their linearity

I was taught that an operator O is linear if $O(cf(x)+dg(x)) = cOf(x)+dOg(x)$  but in my given problem am unable to apply this property

Comment: Can you include what working you did to check the property?

Comment: You might consider splitting these properties up. Check that $O(f+g)=Of+Og$ and that $O(\lambda f)=\lambda O(f)$. Your operator $A$ in particular is not linear: one has $A(\lambda f)=\lambda f(x)+x \neq \lambda (f(x)+x)=\lambda A(f)$